# How much memory your app will take up when develop the android app?

Tags: android, filesize, android-package-managers, android-memory

Sometimes we encounter the `memory issues`,such as the OOM problems.And We inevitably have to manage the memory.Android has set a limit to the memory used bye each app.The maximum limit probably is the `32M`in the early versions of android,such as 1.5,1.6,2.1.

Android of v4.0 has exceeded this limit.We can set android:largeHeap to "true" in the AndroidManifest,so the app could increase the memory limit.

I'm develeping the wallpaper app.The app can show many pictures in high definition.But the memory used by the app always reach the limit of more than 60M in the android of 720p, about 100M in the android of 1080p.

The overuse of memory is unacceptable for me.And I'm looking for the means to resolve it all the time.

My friends,How much memory your app will take up when you develop your app during debugging or running?Is there a `memory-manage mechanism` in the code?Look forward to your reply.

Comment: please use MAT to debug your program, see https://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory used by bitmaps is based on what's in the bitmap, not the size of the file. There's a few things you can do to [reduce the footprint of the bitmap being loaded](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) in to memory, which, in turn will reduce the amount of memory your app is using.

There's a great talk here from Google I/O for [memory management](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) that will help and another that will help you check to see [if you have any memory leaks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dgnx0E7m1GQ) as well.

Also, note that if you use [Bitmap.Config.RGB_565](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) you can half the amount of memory that the Bitmap is using (each pixel value is stored in 2 bytes instead of 4)